# Printing 'self' from 'memory object'

Tags: python

I would be grateful for your advice on this.

So need to implement a function to find out whether a chess piece is at a specific coordinate on a chessboard:

The piece is defined by the class `Piece` and a subclass `Bishop`, `Rook`, etc.

Co-ordinates & side by a tuple `(col, row, side)` and the side represented by a `bool` (`True` for white, `False` for Black)

so assigned an instance variable:

```
wb1 = Bishop (1,1,True)
```

If I try to print `wb1`, returns the memory object

```
<__main__.Bishop object at 0x7fdd440094f0>
```

Is there anyway, I can get it to print `wb1` - the `self` variable, rather the memory object.

Many thanks

Comment: python uses default string representations for objects.  if they're not intentionally defined for a class printing objects may be useless.  try this:  ```print(dir(wb1))``` to see what attributes the Bishop has, then print those things, which may look like ```print(f'{wb1.row}-{wb1.col}-{wb.color}')```  (this example using made-up attributes)

Comment: The term "memory object" is something you just made up. It has no real meaning. You need to override the `__repr__` method

Comment: By your understanding, what's a non-memory object?

Comment: @Alexander It appears that he's using the term for a class whose repr just shows its memory address instead of something nice.

Comment: "f I try to print wb1, returns the memory object" it doesn't *return anything*, it *prints* the string `<__main__.Bishop object at 0x7fdd440094f0>` to standard output. That is the default representation of an object. Why were you *expecting anything else?*

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry new to Py, so apologies if I get the terminology wrong. Basically, wb1 is the White Bishop piece at cord 1,1. If I needed to find out what piece was at coordinate 1,1 - I'd like it to print out wb1 rather than the memory address if that makes sense..so if I had a func like find_piece(1,1) it would return wb1

Comment: @Agyamarky I'm sorry, but that doesn't really clarify anything. What, **exactly** do you expect `print(wb1)` to print? It isn't clear

Comment: the string 'wb1'  and not <__main__.Bishop object at 0x7fdd440094f0>

Comment: @Agyamarky why would it print the string `wb1`? That doesn't make any sense. That's the name of the variable you assigned the object to. The object has *no knowledge* of that name, and moreover, it *shouldn't*. Variables are *source code*, they are for the *programmer*, they shouldn't contain data.

Comment: @Agyamarky To add onto what juanpa said: variable names are meaningless to the computer. They exist for the convenience of the computer. If you would like to make an object be associated with a string like `wb1`, then you need to make that string *part* of the object. Alternatively, you can use a dictionary to key objects by some string value of your chosing

Comment: many thanks guys, will try a dictionary - think that way it might work..